# Best approach to determine PORT number in nodejs app if I need to know the PORT number for other apps

Tags: node.js, port

I've created a local electron app that uses a simple node.js server, and for now, I've set the PORT to listen on 3000. I also have a chrome extension that needs to communicate with this app. They both run locally. Let's say I distribute this app, then I might face an issue where port 3000 is being used by the machine for other processes. In this case, my app would crash. I can't let process.env.PORT determine the port either because I wouldn't be able to explicitly set it in the chrome extension. So I was wondering what the best approach to solve this issue would be. Is there a way to set this up without specifying the port number?